# Different Account that have the same password

Tags: php, mysql

I can log-in in the page but my problem if i have the same password with other account i won't log-in please can you guys tell me what's the problem i really appreciate it if you don't mind helping me I'm a beginner Thx a lot.

```
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE (username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "')");

if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}
```

Comment: This can only happen if you have the same username + password combination more than once in the table so that `mysql_num_rows($login)` is different than 1.

Comment: it should be 1 unless they have both same username which is not logical

Comment: You should make your username field UNIQUE in mysql so this can't happen.

Comment: You appear to be using plain text passwords. Don't do that. Just don't. Use [sha1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) with some salt and pepper.

Comment: @Arjan sha1 is as bad as plain text! Don't ever suggest it again, please. With reasonably priced hardware, you can brute-force millions or billions of passwords per second. There are currently only two approaches: First one is to use a very slow hash function like BCRYPT. Second is to use dedicated crypto hardware (HSM hardware security module) that does the hashing with HMAC SHA256. Not having an HSM leaves you with a very slow hashing algorithm.

Comment: @Sven: duly noted, although I'm not sure how well bcrypt is available in php (and I did advise to add salt and pepper). I could not find a `bcrypt()` function, so I'm probably missing something.

Comment: There is no `bcrypt()`, and if you wanted to use it in the past, it was a hassle to figure out, but PHP 5.5 has easy to use `password_hash()` that works with reasonable defaults, but can be configured as well. [Documentation](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) [Backport to PHP 5.3.7 and up](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Answer (score 4):

You have a duplicate account somewhere.

Notice that your SQL is selecting all users with a given pair of name and password, but it will only authenticate if the result of the query has only one row. Take a look at this more closely:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
```

So, my suggestion is: use an equal-or-greater comparison (`>=`), and eliminate duplicates. Remove the dupes that already exist and come up with a way to avoid creating duplicate name and password pairs.

Comment: If the user name is unique then it's safe to use `==` because more than one row is always an error (should not be possible).

Answer (score 4):

In your table `username` should be **UNIQUE** to avoid this problem of duplication,so try to modify your table and delete duplicated usernames.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `mysql_num_rows($login) == 1`, it should work even if you have two different accounts with the same password. Probably you have two accounts with the same login AND password.. Use a `console.log(mysql_num_rows($login))` after the query and see that probably its returning more than one row.

Like this:

```
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE (username = '" . 

mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "')");
console.log(mysql_num_rows($login));
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer but...

1. Make your username and email fields UNIQUE in your database and use INSERT IGNORE when adding new members. This will prevent duplication.
2. Encrypt your passwords!
3. Don't use mysql for database connections as it's depreciated. Use PDO or mysqli.
4. Don't use SELECT * unless you have to. In this case, SELECT `username` would suffice.
5. Encrypt your passwords!

Never store plain-text passwords in a database - it's very insecure. At the very least, do the following to safeguard your users (and yourself)

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password = sha1($password);
```

This will save you from a lot of headaches :)

Edited to reflect Arjan's comment.

Comment: I don't think that you should modify the password input in any way. If I enter `abc ` then it does not mean I want to use `abc` as my password. And my password `<foo>bar` is not just `bar` (which is what `strip_tags()` creates).

Comment: SHA1 is no secure hashing algorithm for passwords. Do not use it. Do not pretend it adds to security. PHP has a very convenient password hashing function built in since version 5.5, and the backport library works with PHP as low as 5.3.7: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: And what if his version of PHP isn't compatible? SHA1 is better than using nothing at all - which is why I said "at the very least." :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select all from the table where the username matches (as the username normally is unique) and then once you have the row check to see if the passwords match.

If they do match then assign the session variable.

This way would be better then getting both username and password from the array (encase of mistakes).

Side Note: if your storing passwords in a database, they should be encrypted 'hashed' and not raw data for security reasons

Comment: Are you suggesting him to run two queries for authentication?

Comment: no not 2 queries!!! using the database, you get the record using the username and then you get the password from the result and compare that with the form one. Do you not know how mysql works??? Its only 1 query and is cleaner

Comment: @NoLiver92: and what's the benefit? You only need to know if the user name and password combination is correct. The database can check that for you and return one row if there is a match an zero rows if there is no match.